# form file input get cleared when refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, file, input

I have a html form with some text input and a file input (image logo).

Now, if there is an error with one of the text inputs (like length is invalid) when the user click the submit button [client->server(php)->client], the content of the file input is cleared which is annoying!

I set others text input with last values when the page submits with an error, but I cant with a file input. I tried to set the file input value with `document.getElementsByName('logo')[0].value;` to set it in a hidden value but I got the path "C:\fakepath\random-0690.JPG"... this is so shocking, I know its for security purposes but it is shocking...

How i can resolve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer !

This is simple, I created an AJAX call that send the form contents and validate if everything is okay. Then if there are errors, display these (and it will keep the values and file attachments in the form) .. Else : Send the post form and the attached file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You cannot remotely set the value of a file input as a basic security measure. If you could, then it'd be trivial to do `<input type="file" value="/etc/passwd" name="pwn3d" />` and steal any file you want from the user's machine.

There's nothing shocking about it at all. Live with it, or enjoy having your files stolen.

Comment: yeah I understood this scenario, but theres an alternative ?

Comment: No. It's not permitted, period. Do you think hostile users will be nice and not use any "alternative" because the W3C said "pretty please with sugar on top"?